# How to display current_admin_user's name in navigation header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Construction like:

```
  menu.add :label => current_admin_user.full_name do |submenu|
    menus.each do |m|
      submenu.add :label => m['name'],
                  :url => "/admin/change/#{m['id']}",
                  :html_options => {:style => 'float:left;'},
                  :if => proc { current_admin_user.role?('super_admin') }
    end
  end
```

Doesn't work in 1.0pre+ anymore. There is no current_admin_user in the scope. But in the logs i see the request that fetches admin user before a menu getting added.

```
SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 6  ORDER BY `admin_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Any chance to deal with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is still possible to use, i only needed to pass id of a menu

```
  menu.add id: 'user_name' label: -> { current_admin_user.full_name } do |submenu|
```

Comment: It is not clear where to add this code. Under ActiveAdmin.register_page I have a `undefined method `add' for {}:Hash` . activeadmin (2.12.0)

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris in config/initializers/active_admin.rb